# Floyd's Algorithm with a negative cycle

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs

I know that I cannot use Floyd's algorithm if I have a graph with at least one negative cycle, because 
path-lengths between vertices can be arbitrarily small.

I am wondering, how the distance matrices at each iteration of $k$, where $k=0, \dots n$ will look like. 
I now that there will be negative numbers on the main diagonal, but I do not know where they will be. Could somebody explain it to me, please?

I have example with 4 vertices and I know that matrix for $k=0$ is the same as in the case that there are no negative cycles in a graph.

My example (but you can use another graph):

[image]

Matrix for $k=0$ is:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -4 & \infty & 3 \\ 
1 & 0 & \infty & \infty \\
\infty & 2 & 0 & \infty \\
\infty  & \infty & 5 & 0    
\end{bmatrix}